# OwnCloud (migration 6 -> 7) - everything corrupt

Tags: encryption, owncloud

I've been quite happy with Owncloud as have my users, but now recently I believe I have f**cked something up and I hope you can help.
I was running an Owncloud 6 instance on my dedicated debian with the data folder in /home/cloud.
I then recently backed up the database and config/ folder as recommended in order to upgrade to version 7 over the old one.

Since then migrating the mysql db hasn't worked (users, activity, files), the front-end has been extremely slow (~2 mins response time), and no files show up under any users, even as I've been told it re-scans the data folder.
What's even more frustrating, I have the encryption app installed and i constantly keep getting the 'Invalid private key for Encryption App. Please update your private key password in your personal settings to recover access to your encrypted files.' flash message even though I have done so many times. 
As nothing seems to be there/working I have tried moving my photos from my data dir (/home/cloud/andreas/files/photos/) to my own user folder /home/andreas/ and downloading to my local machine. None of the jpgs are opening and their file size seems correct.

What do you recommend? moving all files of all users to a backup dir and completely remove everything Owncloud and start anew? Do I need to decrypt all files to retrieve? How?

Is it generally a bad idea to upgrade the instance? - Why has it been so tedious and problematic even for a person who likes to believe he knows what he's doing? :)

Hope you can shed some light on what I'm supposed to do here.
My jpgs, mp3s - everything is corrupt/unrecognized/not opening...

Thanks in advance,
Andreas

Comment: I recommend you migrate this question to [SU] as it's a question about general hardware and software, and not a programming-related question. Best of luck restoring your data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using encryption, your files only *look* corrupted. Actually, they are encrypted and ownCloud is telling you it cannot decrypt them with *'Invalid private key for Encryption App. Please update your private key password in your personal settings to recover access to your encrypted files.'*

It seems something went wrong during the upgrade which resulted in a broken installation. That you have set `"datadirectory" => '/home/cloud',` makes recovery a little easier. My first advice is to restore a working OC6 with the database and config backup:

1. Rename your owncloud installation directory. You can delete it if recovery was successful.
2. Download and unzip the OC6 version you were using.
3. Restore the Database and config.php from your backup.

That should bring back your files and restore a working installation.

My second advice is to follow [the detailed server upgrade instructions](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/admin_manual/maintenance/update.html#upgrading-the-owncloud-server) and maybe especially the tip in 10. to use `php occ upgrade` on the command line to prevent request timeouts on bigger installations, as well as preventing other users from interfering.

If that still produces a broken installation you can help debug the problem by:

1. Restoring your OC6 as described above
2. Setting `'loglevel' => 0,` in the config array and adding a `define('DEBUG',true);` to config.php
3. Do the update again and create a [new issue](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/new) with [the template](https://raw.github.com/owncloud/core/master/issue_template.md), including suspicious log file entries.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, sorry bout the delay - I'm looking to perhaps code some service that'll mirror the key folders with the actual file folders (recursively) --ahem when i get the time.. have you perhaps heard of any bulk decryption scripts?